# Constants in .NET with String.Format

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have two constants:

```
public const string DateFormatNormal = "MMM dd";
public const string TimeFormatNormal = "yyyy H:mm";
```

Later, I decided to have another constant based on those two:

```
public const string DateTimeFormatNormal = String.Format("{0} {1}", DateFormatNormal, TimeFormatNormal);
```

But I get a compile error: `The expression being assigned to 'Constants.DateTimeFormatNormal' must be constant`

After I try doing it like that:

```
public const string DateTimeFormatNormal = DateFormatNormal + " " + TimeFormatNormal;
```

it is working with `+ " " +`, but I still prefer to use something similar to `String.Format("{0} {1}", ....)`. Any thoughts how I can make it work?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unfortunately not. When using the const keyword, the value needs to be a compile time constant. The reslult of String.Format isn't a compile time constant so it will never work.

You could change from `const` to `readonly` though and set the value in the constructor. Not exact the same thing...but a similar effect.

Comment: You could use readonly and set the value in the variable declaration as well. It doesn't `need` to be in the class constructor.

Answer (score 4):

I find myself in this situation often and I end up converting it to something that looks like:

```
public static readonly string DateTimeFormatNormal = String.Format("{0} {1}", DateFormatNormal, TimeFormatNormal);
```

(Hope that's right, I'm a VB.NET dev, same idea)

```vb
Public Shared ReadOnly DateTimeFormatNormal As String = String.Format("{0} {1}", DateFormatNormal, TimeFormatNormal)
```

`Public Shared ReadOnly` is pretty darn close to `Public Const`.